# Does limitation of size imply axiom of powerset in Morse-Kelly if the generalized continuum hypothesis is included in Morse-Kelley set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose Morse-Kelley set theory consists of class comprehension, class foundation, class extension, axiom of infinity , limitation of size, and the general continuum hypothesis. Can the axiom of powerset,that the power set of a set is a set, be proven in this system? Without gch of course it can’t.

If it can be proven then Morse-Kelley set theory with gch can be presented as class comprehension, class foundation, class extension, axiom of infinity, and the following axiom which combines the axiom of limitation of size and gch: let P be the power class of a class C. If S is a class such that |S|<|P| then there exists an element of P with the same cardinality as S.

Here only one axiom explicitly refers to sets, the axiom of infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot prove powerset even under $\mathsf{GCH}$, although it depends on how we state $\mathsf{GCH}$. Let me follow the following form of $\mathsf{GCH}$:

> For a given set $a$, if the powerset of $a$ exists, then there is a bijection between the powerset $\mathcal{P}(a)$ and $|a|^+$.

The existence of $|a|^+$ requires more justification. It follows from Choice, Replacement, and the existence of $\mathcal{P}(a)$. Since I am unfamiliar with Limitation of size, let me replace it with the combination of Replacement and Global choice, which should imply Limitation of size:

> - Replacement: For every class function $F$ and a set $a$, the image set $F[a] = \{F(x)\mid x\in a\}$ exists.
> - Global choice: There is a class well-order of $V$.

Then we can see the following:

> **Claim.** There is a model of Morse-Kelley set theory plus Global choice, Replacement, $\mathsf{GCH}$, and the negation of Powerset.
>
> *Proof.* Let us work over $\mathsf{ZFC} + (V=L)$ and consider $L_{\omega_1}$. Since $L_{\omega_1} = H_{\omega_1}$, it is a model of second-order $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without powerset. Furthermore, since $L_{\omega_1}\vDash (V=L)$, it satisfies Global Choice, $L_{\omega_1}$ satisfies $\mathsf{GCH}$ vacuously (since every set in there is countable) but it does not satisfy Powerset.

Comment: As far as formulation of gch, I wanted to use a formulation of gch and limitation of size together that does not explicitly refer to sets: given any power class P( a class equal to the power class of some class) and any class S with |S| <|P|, S has the same cardinality as some member of P. I’m pretty sure the answer to my question is no also for this formulation. Does your proof work for this formulation of gch also? Actually I like that gch and limitation of size can be bundled together that natural way as limiting cardinalities of subclasses of power classes.

Comment: @M.Solomon I do not see why your GCH is really the GCH we commonly say, since it follows from the Global Choice that is compatible with the failure of the usual GCH, if my understanding on your power class is correct: I understand your power class as a class $C$ containing all *subsets* of $C$. Then you can see by induction that $V_\alpha\subseteq C$ for every ordinal $\alpha$, so $C=V$. If a class $S$ satisfies $|S|<|V|$, and if we have the Global Choice, then $S$ must be a set so it has the same cardinality with a member of $V$.

Comment: I do consider the power class of a set to be the class of all subsets of that class. My formulation of gch is Let P be the power class of a class C. If |S| < |P| then S has the cardinality of some element of P (in other words the cardinalities of the subclasses of P are already the cardinalities of the elements of P or the cardinality of P).  The case where C is a set is the usual gch, right?  The case where C=V gives the axiom of limitation of size. Am I missing something?

Comment: The issue is that unlike that the powerset of a set has a larger cardinality than the given set, the powerclass of a given class is not necessarily "larger" than the given set. A powerclass of a class is more similar to, something like, a collection of "small" subsets of a given set (e.g., For an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, the collection of all subsets of $\kappa$ of cardinality $<\kappa$, which is completely different from the genuine powerset of $\kappa$.)

Comment: Even your current formulation of GCH is valid over the model $L_{\omega_1}$ I suggested: Take any subset $X\subseteq L_{\omega_1}$, and consider the powerclass $P(X)$ of $X$ computed over $L_{\omega_1}$, which is equal to the set of all *countable* subsets of $X$, whose cardinality is $\omega_1$. If $|S|<|P(X)|$ holds over $(L_{\omega_1}, \mathcal{P}(L_{\omega_1}))$, then $|S|<|P(X)| = \omega_1$ holds over $L$. This implies $S$ is countable, so it has the same cardinality with some member of $P(X)$.

Comment: As I stated before, the power class of a given class does not represent the "true" collection of all possible "subclasses" of a given class (which will be a third-order object rather than a second-order object, or in other words, a class.) Thus the powerclass of a proper class does not have the "right" size, which could be out of your intention.

Comment: I think you have shown that you answered  my question negatively for my formulation of gch also. Thanks! But I still don’t understand how my formulation of gch contradicts the usual one.

Comment: @M.Solomon I did not say your GCH is not contradictory with the usual one. But it is not the right formulation of GCH for "class-sized cardinals," and I guess there is no such.

Comment: I just noticed that your above argument that V is the only proper class that is a power class uses a different concept of power class than I used. You say that C is a power class if it contains each subset of C. I say that P is a power class if it equals the class of all subsets of some class C. P and C don’t have to be the same. For example let C = the class of all single element sets. C is a proper class that does not satisfy the condition in the axiom but the power class P of C, which is not  V, does satisfy that condition by limitation of size and the power class property.

Comment: It is true that the only proper class case of the axiom that matters is the V case, which gives limitation of choice.

Comment: And that the case of the axiom where where C is a set and P is the power set of C is the usual gch, which says that the cardinality of P is the next highest cardinality after the cardinality of C, whereas the case where C is a proper class yields that the cardinality of V, and hence of any proper class, is the next highest cardinality after the cardinalities of the sets. Of course by limitation of size there is no cardinality higher than the cardinality of C if C is a proper class.

Comment: @M.Solomon I put my interpretation of "power class" in my earlier comment, and I noticed latter that you did not use this definition. My example still works under your notion, however.

Comment: And in fact your definition works as well (in a way better) than mine since V is the only proper class case we care about and V satisfies your definition. I only pointed out the difference in case it had to do with your apparent objection to the axiom that combines gch and limitation of size based on power class concept. I think your objection is you view the set and the proper class classes of this axiom as being very different in spirit,  due to difficulty of defining a reasonable power class concept for proper classes.  Differences are given in my above comments.

Comment: But the common spirit connecting the two cases is that both say a power class has cardinality as close as possible to the cardinality of the class it’s the power class of. If C is a set by cantor’s theorem the cardinality of its power class P is greater so the cardinality of P is the next higher cardinality after the cardinality of C. If C is a proper class the cardinality of P is the cardinality of C. Also the power class property is instrumental in proving limitation of size from global axiom of choice, so we claim the power class property appears naturally in the axiom.

Comment: Note that the set case of the axiom (gch) is more controversial than the proper class case (limitation of size).